# Usage of Unit of Work in DataPower

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

I have set the Unit of Work to 1 and turned on the Backout by giving backout queue name and all.

To see how it works , I gave a wrong Queue name which wont exist.

But I can see there is no retry happening and according to the threshold value and message is being discarded without sending it to blackout queue.

SO can anyone explain , is it like if there is any issue in Datapower the only this retry will work ?

Thanks & Regards,
Sreevathsa A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in to various blogs,got to know that there is a settings under Advaced as " Process Backend Errors". After setting it "Off" , the error rule started getting triggered.

Thanks & regards, Sreevathsa A